# What LEGO set is this thrift store find from, dark red and dark grey?

Tags: set-identification

The part from a thrift store box of LEGO parts:

[image: assembly photo]

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be the main model from [Ronin R.E.X. (70735-1)](https://brickset.com/sets/70735-1/Ronin-R-E-X):

[image: set image]